# Sinatra randomly starts demo server

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am writing a small proxy-checking utility, here is my code so far:

```
require "thread"
require "socket"
require "http"
require "sinatra"

host = "0.0.0.0"
port = 6660

Thread.new do
  class App < Sinatra::Base
    set :server, :thin

    get '/' do
      env.select {|k,v| k.start_with? 'HTTP_'}.collect {|pair| "#{pair[0].sub(/^HTTP_/, '')}: #{pair[1]}"}.join "\n"
    end
  end

  App.run! host: host, port: port
end

sleep 2

queue = Queue.new

ext_ip = Socket.ip_address_list.detect{|intf| intf.ipv4?}.ip_address # and !intf.ipv4_loopback? and !intf.ipv4_multicast? and !intf.ipv4_private?}
url = "http://#{url}:#{port}/"

Thread.new do
  queue << proxy.split(":") while proxy = gets.chomp
end

servers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map {
  Thread.new do
    until queue.empty?
      p "shit", queue.pop
      headers = HTTP.via(*queue.pop).get(url).split("\n").map {|l| l.split(" ", 2)}.to_h
      p headers
    end
  end
}.each do |t|
  t.join
end
```

For some reason, this does not only start a sinatra server on localhost:6660 but also on `localhost:4567`, and I absolutely don't understand why.

This is the output I get:

```
== Sinatra (v1.4.6) has taken the stage on 6660 for development with backup from Thin
Thin web server (v1.6.3 codename Protein Powder)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on localhost:6660, CTRL+C to stop
Stopping ...
== Sinatra has ended his set (crowd applauds)
== Sinatra (v1.4.6) has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from Thin
Thin web server (v1.6.3 codename Protein Powder)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on localhost:4567, CTRL+C to stop
```

Where does that second server come from?? When I open it in my browser it is the default Sinatra splash.

Comment: I wouldn't call that "random" if it happens everytime. More like unexpectedly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than `require "sinatra"`, use [`require "sinatra/base"`](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Sinatra::Base%20-%20Middleware,%20Libraries,%20and%20Modular%20Apps). Requiring just `sinatra` enables the built in server, which will start [serving the (empty) `Sinatra::Application` app in an `at_exit` handler](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.4.6/lib/sinatra/main.rb#L25).